# How can I call a variadic C function with a list of arguments pulled from a rust Vec?

Tags: rust, variadic-functions

I am trying to call the JNI function `CallStaticVoidMethod` from rust.  The jni-sys wrapper declares it as

```
pub CallStaticVoidMethod:
    Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(env: *mut JNIEnv, cls: jclass, methodID: jmethodID, ...)>,
```

I would like to wrap this call in something safer, so I have created this method on my wrapper object:

```
pub fn call_static_void_method(&mut self, cls: jclass, method: jmethod, args: & Vec<jobject>)
{
    let csvm;
    unsafe {
        csvm = (**self.env_ptr).CallStaticVoidMethod.expect("no implementation of CallStaticVoidMethod");
    }
    unsafe {
        return csvm(self.env_ptr, cls, method, /*what here?*/);
    }
}
```

How can I convert `args:Vec<jobject>` so that I can provide the final arguments to the `CallStaticVoidMethod` JNI function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call variadic C functions from rust in the normal way, however calling them with an argument list that is only known at runtime is another matter. From what I understand, it is not even really possible in C (at least not in a standards compliant manner).

Luckily, though, it looks as though you don't need to do that. The JNI provides an alternative method, `CallStaticVoidMethodA`, which is defined as:

```
NativeType CallStaticVoidMethodA(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jmethodID methodID, jvalue *args);
```

where `args` points to an array containing the arguments, in the form of `jvalue`.

You are receiving a `Vec<jobject>`; a `jvalue` is a union of various kinds of value, so you will need to convert your `Vec<jobject>` into an array of `jvalue`s. Alternatively it would be more flexible if your function could accept `Vec<jvalue>` as you would be able to call methods that accept various argument types - in that case you could just pass `args.as_ptr()` like so:

```
pub fn call_static_void_method(&mut self, cls: jclass, method: jmethod, args: & Vec<jvalue>)
{
    let csvm;
    unsafe {
        csvm = (**self.env_ptr).CallStaticVoidMethodA.expect("no implementation of CallStaticVoidMethodA");
    }
    unsafe {
        return csvm(self.env_ptr, cls, method, args.as_ptr());
    }
}
```

There are variations on this theme for all of the JNI functions for calling methods.

See also: [JNI Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#callstatictypemethod-routines-callstatictypemethoda-routines-callstatictypemethodv-routines)

Comment: maybe, https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.VaList.html#method.as_va_list, but this is very unconventional to create a va_list at the hand in C (in fact I don't think it's possible).

Comment: @Stargateur I hadn't noticed that - but since JNI provides an interface that takes a simple array, I would still use that in preference, rather than use an experimental nightly feature.